# Python: most recent call last error

Tags: python

Can't understand the error in this as the brackets are as per directions

```
mean=df["Normalized-losses"].mean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aarushi Goyal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 822, in _ensure_numeric
    x = float(x)
```

Please provide solution

Comment: Remove the dot after df

Comment: If you want us to help with an error, you have to give us the whole error. You cut off the most important line, that tells you what kind of error it is, and describes what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the column into numeric using

```
pd.to_numeric(df['Normalized-losses'], errors = 'coerce')
```

Then try:

```
mean = df['Normalized-losses'].mean()
```

You can also use:

```
mean = df.loc[:, 'Normalized-losses'].mean()
```

If it doesn't help do provide more info regarding the error.

Comment: mean=df.loc[:,"Normalized-losses"].mean()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Aarushi Goyal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py", line 822, in _ensure_numeric
    x = float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '???164164?158?158?192192188188????

Comment: @AarushiGoyal The error you are getting is due to string values in your column. Try to convert the column to numeric first using:                           
 pd.to_numeric(df['Normalized-losses'], errors = 'coerce')

Comment: hey! it worked! can you please explain the first comment. why did you take pd.to_numeric and errors=coerce

Comment: `pd.to_numeric` will convert all values in the given column in this case Normalized losses to numeric values & In any case if any values in the column fail to convert into numeric then using `errors = "coerce"` will set those values as None.  Read the documentation for more info. [Click here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable "Normalized-losses" would be a non-numerical type variable.

Try pandas dtypes method to check data type:

`df.dtypes`

If its non-numerical then use `astype()` method to change the data type.